# Protocol won't be executed Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, protocols

I'm writing simple math game with swift and I have a problem with protocol. But first, I have 3 `UIViewController's`, 2 `SKScene` and one `NavigationViewController`. [image]

First menu is game mode menu and second is difficulties menu, I want to second one be interactive and has gravity so I decided to make it in `SKScene`.
[image]

When user click on menu button it should go back to main menu. It works only when I'm going from main menu but when user lost the game and go back from gameScene to difficulties menu, and then click menu button protocol isn't executed. I don't know why because it should. (enum skad1 is enumeration that contains from where the difficulties menu is showed (from main menu or from game))

My main menu code:

```
    import UIKit

class MyMainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func dividingclicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    skad = .menu
    let gameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gamemenu")
    navigationController?.pushViewController(gameVC!, animated: true)    
}


}
```

My difficulties menu `ViewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

enum skad1 {
 case gra,menu
}
var skad = skad1.gra

class MyGVViewController: UIViewController, GameViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Menugame") {
            let gameScene = scene as! MySKScene
            gameScene.gameViewControllerDelegate = self
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill


            gameScene.size = view.bounds.size

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

func goback() {
    print("goback executed")
    let view = self.view as! SKView?
    view?.presentScene(nil)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
func goback2() {
    print("goback2 executed")
    let view = self.view as! SKView?
    view?.presentScene(nil)
    }

    }
```

And my Difficulties menu `SkScene` code:

```
import GameKit
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

protocol GameViewControllerDelegate: class {
func goback()
func goback2()
}



class MySKScene: SKScene {

//Variables

var motionManager: CMMotionManager!
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var ball1 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball2 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball3 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball4 = SKSpriteNode()
weak var gameViewControllerDelegate: GameViewControllerDelegate?

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if ball.contains(location){
            showgame(zakres: 200)
        }else if ball1.contains(location){
            showgame(zakres: 100)
        }else if ball2.contains(location) {
            showgame(zakres: 50)
        }else if ball3.contains(location) {
            showgame(zakres: 150)
        }else if ball4.contains(location) {
            if skad == .menu{
                print("should execut goback")
                self.gameViewControllerDelegate?.goback()
            }else{
                print("should execut goback2")
                self.view?.presentScene(nil)
                gameViewControllerDelegate?.goback2()
            }
        }
    }
}

func showgame(zakres:Int) {

    if let view = self.view {
        range = zakres
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            let gameScene = scene as! GameScene
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            gameScene.size = view.bounds.size
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball1 = self.childNode(withName: "ball1") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball2 = self.childNode(withName: "ball2") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball3 = self.childNode(withName: "ball3") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball4 = self.childNode(withName: "ball4") as! SKSpriteNode
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody = border
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 20, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 35)
    }
}
```

}

Ps. What should I add to protocol function `goback2` to load main view controller?

Comment: Read up about unwind segues